# Why outlook does not convert &amp; as an ampersand

Tags: html, outlook, escaping

In HTML, `&amp;` stands for `&`. So when i send a mail with some content with `&amp;` in it why does outlook not convert it as `&`, even when the format is selected as HTML.

For example if i am sending `Dolce &amp; Gabbana`, it is showing as `Dolce &amp; Gabbana` instead of `Dolce & Gabbana`.

Comment: which language you are using to send emails? the content type of email should be like Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8".

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Answer (score 1):

When typed in Outlook, `&amp;` does not produce an ampersand for the same reason that `<p>` does not produce a paragraph element.

Outlook HTML encodes user input so that the message is valid HTML and more importantly so that it reads the same to the recipient as it does to the author.

`&amp;` becomes `&amp;amp;`, `<p>` becomes `&lt;p&gt;`.

I'm not certain that Outlook provides a way to insert raw HTML, however the HTML mode does allow rich text features to be used, and also allows formatting to be preserved when copying and pasting from the clipboard.